# accessing objects in $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, json

So, i used $.getJSON to get the objects from openweathermap API. Below is what I get in my console when I try to type:

```
console.log(data[0])
```

I want to access 'icon'. I tried:

```
data[0]["icon"] and data[0].icon
```

However, it was to no avail.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

[$.getJSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTO4J.png)

(edit #1)
Here is my code:

```
$.getJSON(weatherlink, function(json1) {
    $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
        // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: points,
        labelContent: title,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 20),
        labelClass: "label",
            // icon: "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" +data[0]["icon"]+ ".png"
        });
    markersWeather.push(marker);
    marker.setMap(map);
    console.log(data[0]);
    });
})
```

weatherlink is a variable containing the link to the API.

(edit #2)
[this is how the entire data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz6R5.png)

(edit #3)
it is giving me undefined when i do either way.

Comment: Show the code for how you use `$.getJSON`.

Comment: @Arg0n I have edited my post.

Comment: Show entire `data` as JSON, prefferably in your question.

Comment: I have updated my post @Arg0n. Is that clearer now?

Comment: What is your mean of  "it was to no avail".?You have error ?

Comment: It gives me 'undefined' when i try to key in data[0]["icon"] or data[0].icon @ashkufaraz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start at `json1[0]` instead of `data`:

```js
var icon;

json1 = [{
  "icon": "04n"
}];

$.each(json1, function() {

  icon = "<img src = http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + json1[0].icon + ".png>"
});

$('#output').html(icon);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

json1 (Object) is inside loop you can use a condition like
`if ( key == 'icon' )` or `if ( json1.hasOwnProperty( 'icon' ) ),`
if it matches a condition use variable like data or `json1[key]`

If you want to get the value outside of the loop, use `json1['icon'].`

Answer (score 0):

Try this(data[key]['icon']):

```
$.getJSON(weatherlink, function(json1) {
    $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
        // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: points,
        labelContent: title,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 20),
        labelClass: "label",
            // icon: "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" +data[0]["icon"]+ ".png"
        });
    markersWeather.push(marker);
    marker.setMap(map);
    console.log(data[key]['icon']);
    });
})
```